# Implement an indexible interface

Tags: typescript

How would I implement an interface that is indexible:

```
interface fooInterface{
    // indexable
    [index:string]:number;
    [index:number]:number;          
}


class Foo implements fooInterface{
    // What goes here? 
}
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/01/24/interfaces-walkthrough.aspx - Half way down you'll find 'Describing an Indexable Object'. My reading is that you don't ever implement it in the class definition, but only by addressing `instance[index]` - so your `fooInterface` can't be used via `implements` but only structurally, eg: `var foo: fooInterface = {};` Not certain this is correct, though - hence comment rather than answer.

Comment: That is actually correct. Would be happy to mark that as answer. Its not in the class specification.

Comment: There are other things in typescript interfaces as well that you cannot implement in a class e.g. call signatures

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't ever implement it in the class definition, but only by addressing `instance[index]`, so your `fooInterface` cannot be be used via `implements` on a TypeScript class, but can be used to describe the expected structure of an object, e,g. `var foo: fooInterface = {};`

> Describing an Indexable Object
>
> A common pattern in JavaScript is to use an object (e.g. {}) as way to
>   map from a set of strings to a set of values. When those values are of
>   the same type, you can use an interface to describe that indexing into
>   an object always produces values of a certain type (in this case,
>   Widget).

```
interface WidgetMap {
    [name: string]: Widget;
}

var map: WidgetMap = {};
map['gear'] = new GearWidget();
var w = map['gear']; // w is inferred to type Widget
```

Quote and Widget example taken from: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/01/24/interfaces-walkthrough.aspx