# Implementing TypeScript interface with bare function signature plus other fields

Tags: interface, typescript

How do I write a class that implements this TypeScript interface (and keeps the TypeScript compiler happy):

```
interface MyInterface {
    (): string;
    text2(content: string);
}
```

I saw this related answer:
[How to make a class implement a call signature in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769636/how-to-make-a-class-implement-a-call-signature-in-typescript)

But that only works if the interface only has the bare function signature. It doesn't work if you have additional members (such as function text2) to be implemented.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248812/implement-an-indexible-interface#comment23254752_16248812

Comment: Short answer is "classes can't match that interface" mentioned in the question you linked http://stackoverflow.com/a/12770145/390330

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A class cannot implement everything that is available in a typescript interface. Two prime examples are callable signatures and index operations e.g. : [Implement an indexible interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248812/implement-an-indexible-interface)

The reason is that an interface is primarily designed to describe anything that JavaScript objects can do. Therefore it needs to be really robust. A TypeScript class however is designed to represent specifically the prototype inheritance in a more OO conventional / easy to understand / easy to type way.

You can still create an object that follows that interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
    (): string;
    text2(content: string);
}

var MyType = ((): MyInterface=>{
  var x:any = function():string { // Notice the any 
      return "Some string"; // Dummy implementation 
  }
  x.text2 = function(content:string){
      console.log(content); // Dummy implementation 
  }
  return x;
}
);
```

Comment: Is there any way of doing this without the intermediate cast to `any`?

Doing it this way, you are effectively bypassing the type system and you could assign literally anything to `x` without getting any error from the compiler.

Answer (score 20):

There's an easy and type-safe way to do this with ES6's `Object.assign`:

```
const foo: MyInterface = Object.assign(
  // Callable signature implementation
  () => 'hi',
  {
    // Additional properties
    text2(content) { /* ... */ }
  }
)
```

Intersection types, which I don't think were available in TypeScript when this question was originally asked and answered, are the secret sauce to getting the typing right.

Comment: This isn't quite type safe since ``Object.assign`` returns ``any``.

Comment: In the current version of TS it's `assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U`

Comment: @Flavien the current signatures look like this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L4438

Comment: As of typescript 2.3 this returns the correct type without using "any" or mutating objects.  Seems to me the best approach with the current version of TS.

Comment: It is definitely mutating objects (the first argument). The typing has been right since TS 2.0.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an elaboration on [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16508581/238753).

As far as I know, the only way to implement a call-signature is to use a function/method. To implement the remaining members, just define them on this function. This might seem strange to developers coming from C# or Java, but I think it's normal in JavaScript.

In JavaScript, this would be simple because you can just define the function and then add the members. However, TypeScript's type system doesn't allow this because, in this example, `Function` doesn't define a `text2` member.

So to achieve the result you want, you need to bypass the type system while you define the members on the function, and then you can cast the result to the interface type:

```
//A closure is used here to encapsulate the temporary untyped variable, "result".
var implementation = (() => {
    //"any" type specified to bypass type system for next statement.
    //Defines the implementation of the call signature.
    var result: any = () => "Hello";

    //Defines the implementation of the other member.
    result.text2 = (content: string) => { };

    //Converts the temporary variable to the interface type.
    return <MyInterface>result;
})(); //Invokes the closure to produce the implementation
```

Note that you don't need to use a closure. You could just declare your temporary variable in the same scope as the resulting interface implementation. Another option is to name the closure function to improve readability.

Here's what I think is a more realistic example:

```
interface TextRetriever {
    (): string;
    Replace(text: string);
}

function makeInMemoryTextRetriever(initialText: string) {
    var currentText = initialText;
    var instance: any = () => currentText;
    instance.Replace = (newText: string) => currentText = newText;

    return <TextRetriever>instance;
}

var inMemoryTextRetriever = makeInMemoryTextRetriever("Hello");
```