# Typescript: Implementing an Interface with a static/unnamed function

Tags: typescript

I need to implement the following (simplified) Typescript Interface of an `d.ts` file:

```
interface SomeLibrary {
    someProperty: SomePropertyClass;
    someMethod();
    (someParam: string): SomeClass; // don't know hot to implement this
}
```

How do I implement this interface in an own class? Especially the unnamed method is problematic. How are those methods called?

Comment: This is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508435/implementing-typescript-interface-with-bare-function-signature-plus-other-fields

Answer (score 2):

The interface you have shown can't be satisfied by a class in TypeScript.

Interfaces like this are usually created to describe a library that uses a different pattern.

One example of how you can satisfy the interface is shown below:

```
var example: SomeLibrary = <any> function(someParam: string) {
    console.log('function called');
    return new SomeClass();
}
example.someProperty = new SomePropertyClass();
example.someMethod = function () { console.log('method called'); };

var x = example('x');
var y = example.someProperty;
var z = example.someMethod();
```

Comment: What does the `<any>` in this example mean?

Comment: The function in that expression doesn't actually satisfy the interface (because it is missing the `someProperty` and `someMethod` members). For this reason, you need to wiggle the type to tell the compiler *I know that this type will be okay, even though it doesn't look like it is to you*. If you forgot to add the next two lines, you'd cause a runtime problem though!

Comment: Is it a cast to the any type?

Comment: Yes - a type assertion that widens the function to `any`, so it can then be narrowed by the preceding `SomeLibrary` type annotation.