# Typescript definition for existing jQuery plugin with nested function

Tags: typescript

I am converting a large JS file that has a lot of jQuery plugins to use TypeScript so I need to also create the necessary TS definition files. I have run into a plugin that I can't figure out the definition file for.

Example of the plugin:

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.foo = function (options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        one: false,
        two: true
    }, options);

    //do something
};

$.fn.foo.bar = function (input) {

    return input;
};
})(jQuery);
```

Example of the usage:

```
$('#list').foo({
one: true});

var updatedHtml = $('#label').foo.bar("hello world");
```

TypeScript defintion (so far):

```
 interface JQuery {
 foo(options: any) : JQuery;
}
```

Based on what I have so far, the first use case is covered, but not the second. How do I write the definition file so that it covers both use cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an anonymous interface (or whatever it is officially called) to define a function and its static fields together:

```
interface JQuery {
    foo: {
        (options: any): JQuery;
        bar: <T>(input: T) => T
    }
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20JQuery%20%7B%0A%09foo%3A%20%7B%0A%09%09%28options%3A%20any%29%3A%20JQuery%3B%0A%09%09bar%3A%20%3CT%3E%28input%3A%20T%29%20%3D%3E%20T%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Adeclare%20var%20%24%3A%20JQuery%3B%0A%0A%24.foo%28%7B%7D%29%20%2F%2F%20okay%0A%0A%24.foo.bar%20%2F%2F%20okay%0A%0A%24.foo.bar%28123%29.toPrecision%20%2F%2F%20type%20preserved)

See also: [Implementing TypeScript interface with bare function signature plus other fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16508435/499922)