# Implementation of interfaces typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5, typescript1.4

```
interface A {
(obj? : any) : any;
func1() : void;
func2() :void;
}
```

How do I write a class B that would implement A? How would I implement the parametrized constructor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing TypeScript interface with bare function signature plus other fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508435/implementing-typescript-interface-with-bare-function-signature-plus-other-fields)

Comment: The solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Why not what's wrong?

Comment: The variable needs a typedef. And so when I mention that it's of any particular type, either of type A or of type"any" I get errors

Answer (score 1):

An interface cannot, by definition, contain a constructor. You have to move it in your implemented class :

```
interface A {
    func1(): void;
    func2(): void;
}

class B implements A {
    constructor(obj? : any) {

    }

    func1() {

    }

    func2() {

    }
}
```