# Use object spread operator to construct function object with fields

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-next

I have successfully created a function object with additional fields using the following `Object.assign`:

```
Object.assign((a) => {
        // Do something....
    }, {
        x: 10
    })
```

... by following a discussion on typescript interfaces: [Implementing TypeScript interface with bare function signature plus other fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508435/implementing-typescript-interface-with-bare-function-signature-plus-other-fields)

However, **I find the Object.assign syntax hard to read**, is there an **object spread operator** way of doing this?

Simply putting the function and object in curly brackets with two spreads does not seem to cut it:

```
{...(a) => a, ...{x: 10}}
```

It gives an error in Typescript and seems to skip the function signature runtime.

EDIT:

Basically I want to do the following (using typescript type-markup):

```
interface IFunc {(a) : string}
interface IStruct {x: number}
type IInteresting = IFunc & IStruct
```

Using @icepickle 's approach of `{(a) => a, ...{x: 'y'}}` just gives tons of errors.  Seems I have to force cast the instance into the target type and then assign the property mutation style.

Comment: After reading the MDN for [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) more closer, it's first parameter isn't a callback function.  I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with it

Comment: @user2340824 functions can also be assigned with properties :). I wonder if `{ (a) => a, ...{x: 10} }` wouldn't cut it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible, because when you use spread properties, the result will always be a plain object. For example, if you take a `Date` object and try to assign additional properties to it, you'll get a plain object instead of a `Date` object.

```js
console.log({ ...new Date(), x: 10 } instanceof Date); // false
```

[Try this in Babel REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=stage-0&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=console.log(%7B%20...new%20Date()%2C%20x%3A%2010%20%7D%20instanceof%20Date)%3B%20%2F%2F%20false&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true).

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not. Object spread syntax is part of *object literals*, which always create (non-function) `Object` objects.