# TypeScript: Implement interface with both call signature and constructor signature

Tags: typescript, types

Is it possible create an object that implements the following interface:

```
interface I {
    (): string;
    new(): any;
}
```

I saw that it is possible to implement an interface having a call signature and some fields from this question: [Implementing TypeScript interface with bare function signature plus other fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508435/implementing-typescript-interface-with-bare-function-signature-plus-other-fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around, it is clearly possible for an object to implement the an interface with both a constructor signature and a call signature:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L142 is an example of this.

The underlying function seems to be the same, albeit called in two different ways:

```
new Object(3);
```

and

```
Object(3);
```