# TypeScript: Implement an interface with both call signature and indexing signature

Tags: typescript, types

I would like to create an object that satisfies this type:

```
interface I {
    (): string;
    [x: string]: number;
}
```

and passes TypeScript type checking. Ideally I would like to not need to resort to tricks such as using `any` as an intermediate step.

I know additional fields can be added to an interface having a call signature, as described here: [Implementing TypeScript interface with bare function signature plus other fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508435/implementing-typescript-interface-with-bare-function-signature-plus-other-fields).

I tried writing:

```
const foo: I = Object.assign(
    // Callable signature implementation
    () => 'hi',
    {
        // Additional properties
        text2: 3
    }
)
```

but I get the error: `Type '(() => "hi") & { text2: number; }' is not assignable to type 'I'.  Index signature is missing in type '(() => "hi") & { text2: number; }'.`

I'd be curious to know if there's a way to create an object implementing interface `I`.

Comment: I reported a bug on your issue, it would help if you provided your real world use-case where you encountered this issue. 10x https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23226

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I didn't encounter this issue in the wild. I'm doing a project on the TypeScript type system and I was trying to see whether a call signature and an indexing signature can coexist. I'll follow the issue you filed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without an assertion if you don't define the type as an interface but rather a type alias for an intersection type:

```
type I =  {
    (): string;
} & {
    [x: string]: number;
}
// Will work
let d:I= Object.assign(function() { return ""}, {
    text: 10
});
```

Not sure why one works but not the other, their public structure is essentially the same, it could be a compiler bug.

**Edit** Submitted a [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23226) we'll have to wait for a reply

Comment: It's apparently [by design](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300), at least for now, but the issue is still marked as "in discussion"

Comment: @jcalz Are you sure this is the same issue ? The problem above manifests even with  `type I =  {
    (): string;
    [x: string]: number;
}` And from what I read in the discussion since it's a `type` it should have worked

Comment: I didn't try with `type`... interesting. I'll look into it more.

Comment: I guess implicit index signatures are weird... maybe I'll file an issue about this and see what people think.

Comment: @jcalz do you mind if I do? I've been wanting to get involved for a while and this seems like a good issue, I was going to investigate it later today

Comment: @jcalz took me a bit longer, finally submitted the bug :)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20I%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20()%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bx%3A%20string%5D%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%22hello%22%0D%0Aa%5B%22yolo%22%5D%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20b%3A%20I%20%3D%20a%20as%20I%3B)

Basically you first declare a function with the correct call signature,
then add any property with the correct index signature. Then return the value (or assign to a new reference like in the example) using the `as` keyword for type assertion.

Event [simpler](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20I%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20()%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bx%3A%20string%5D%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%22hello%22%0D%0Aa%5B%22yolo%22%5D%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20b%3A%20I%20%3D%20a%20as%20I%3B), use type asstertion in the first declaration.

Comment: I would suspect that works mostly because TypeScript allows unchecked type casts. For example, this also works: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20I%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20()%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bx%3A%20string%5D%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%22hello%22%0D%0Aa%5B%22yolo%22%5D%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0Aa%5B%22yoooolo%22%5D%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%22abc%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20b%3A%20I%20%3D%20a%20as%20I%3B

Comment: yes that's true, I updated. You can use the type assertion in the declaration. As a side note, this has drawbacks, can you still use the function prototype's methods ? You may need to inerhit or merge some interfaces if you want to retain those methods.

Comment: The two links you provided contain the same code. Try pressing the `Share` button to generate a new link.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that by using `as`, you are effectively bypassing the type system and are exploiting the known sources of unsoundness present in TypeScript. I was looking if there's a way to get the desired typing without using type casts, going through `any` or similar functionality.

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20a%3A%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%201%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20a%20as%20B%3B