# Angular2 typescript syntax

Tags: angular, typescript

I understand that we can specify the type of a variable in TypeScript using a colon. Here, `_emitters` is a variable which has a type which is specified after the colon sign.

However I am struggling to understand what type is assigned to `_emitters` in the below code.

```
private static _emitters: { [ID: string]: EventEmitter<any> } = {};
```

It is probably very basic, but unfortunately I am unable to understand it.

Comment: You need to go through the TS docs. It's well explained there. Google for "indexable types". See [the relevant documentation here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types). Also, you need to be clear on the difference between Angular and TypeScript. What you are asking has nothing to do with Angular (other than the fact that `EventEmitter` is an Angular type). Finally, the `angular` tag is for the old Angular 1. You are looking for the `angular2` tag.

Comment: @torazaburo angular2 tag doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @torazaburo I thought the tag naming convention were angularjs for ng1 and simply angular for ng2 and up?

Comment: @RomanC Thanks for pointing that out, I had been following the discussion on meta but didn't realize the tags had finally been changed.

Comment: @torazaburo If you like the discussion there's [another one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338485/573032) similar to this case.

Comment: Thanks @torazaburo. 'Indexable Types' was just the keyword that i was looking for. Also found another SO post that helps with Indexable Types. [in this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248812/implement-an-indexible-interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an object that has keys of type string. Each key of the object holds an EventEmitter.

The example is missing the type of emitted value, eg.

```
EventEmitter<string>
```