# Typescript class with static functions that implement an interface with string index

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```js
interface StringDoers {
  [key: string]: (s: string) => void;
}

class MyStringDoers implements StringDoers {
  public static print(s: string) {
    console.log(s);
  }
  public static printTwice(s: string) {
    console.log(s);
    console.log(s);
  }
}
```

This gives me a type error:

> Class 'MyStringDoers' incorrectly implements interface 'StringDoers'.
>
> Index signature is missing in type 'MyStringDoers'

But from Javascript's point of view, it *does* implement `StringDoers`. In a Javascript console I can do this perfectly well:

```js
class MyStringDoers {
    static print(s) {
        console.log(s);
    }
    static printTwice(s) {
        console.log(s);
        console.log(s);
    }
}
MyStringDoers["printTwice"]("hello");
```

I wondered if it is because `[string]` can also return `undefined`, e.g.

```
MyStringDoers["foo"]; // undefined
```

However even changing the interface to this does not work:

```
interface StringDoers {
  [key: string]: ((s: string) => void) | undefined;
}
```

How can I make this work? The constraint is that `StringDoers` is in a third party library so I cannot change it. And I want an actual type that knows about all of the methods - i.e. not just:

```
const doers: StringDoers = {
   print(s: string) {
       console.log(s);
   },
   ...
}
```

I expect someone who doesn't know the answer will try to make themselves feel better by asking why I'd want to do this, so: my use case is adding proper typing for Vuex's `MutationTree`.

Comment: Similar but no. My question is why static functions don't implement the index. Not how to implement the index itself.

Comment: _it does implement StringDoers_ - no it doesn't. Static properties have nothing to do with implementing interface

Comment: @Timmmm I still think it's a duplicate of that question, though. The answer you accepted is misleading. Although not technically wrong it just circumvents the error message. In fact, it is worse than not implementing the interface at all. You could add any static method to your class like `public static meth(n: number): string { /* */ }` and still have a valid class without any compiler warnings. In that case implementing the interface doesn't add any meaning to it. The real answer is in the question I linked to: you can't implement indexable types in a class the way you want to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement an indexible interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248812/implement-an-indexible-interface).

Comment: Yes it circumvents the error message but isn't that the only option, because Typescript isn't smart enough to know that functions *are* accessed by `[key: string]`. What's the difference between `MyStringDoers['foo']` and `map['foo']`? Nothing in terms of the types as far as I can tell.

Comment: Unfortunately the accepted answer doesn't work in my case, because Vuex discovers all the keys via `for (var key of object)`, and class methods do not appear in that list. :-/

Comment: What's the purpose of  the `class` here?

Comment: It's to provide a type for Vuex mutators, getters and setters. The actual type is a map from string to function, but I want Typescript to know the valid function names. So my plan was to make this class, feed it into Vuex, and then give Vuex an extra getter that casts the map back to this class.

Comment: (I know that is ugly as hell - if you have a better way that doesn't involve changing Vuex or repeating myself, I'm all ears!)

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have to annotate the class as accepting string indexes similarly to how its done in the interface (note no concrete function definition):

```
interface StringDoers {
  [key: string]: (s: string) => void;
}

class MyStringDoers implements StringDoers {
  [key: string]: (s: string) => void;

  public static print(s: string) {
    console.log(s);
  }
  public static printTwice(s: string) {
    console.log(s);
    console.log(s);
  }
}
```